# Как передать HTML из div созданный ng-repeat в div id="playZone"

Tags: angularjs

```
<div id="playZone"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card" ng-repeat="cards in ['one','two','three']" ng-click="cardMove()" > {{cards}} </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что конкретно вы хотите передать?

Comment: С помощью cardMove( ) html который создает ng-repeat (три дива с классом 'card') копировался бы при нажатии на любой из них в див с id='playZjone'.  Ну типа this.innerHTML = document.getElementById('playZone').innerHTML

Comment: А зачем вы это хотите сделать? Поясните в вопросе конечную цель, которой вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Цель такая кликаю на "one"  перепрыгивает в див с id="playZone", кликаю на "three" перепрыгивает  "three" .

Comment: Как  зацепиться за див созданный 'на лету' ng-repeat ?

Comment: Комментарии никто не читает, поправте вопрос. Если кликните на "править" прямо под вопросом, то перепрыгнете в правку вопроса.

Comment: Комментарии читают, если непосредственно обратиться к человеку @0xdb. Не путайте новичков)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае в ангуляре делается вот так:

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/3gzcm5aL/)

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.currentCard = null;
    vm.cardMove = function(card) {
      vm.currentCard = card;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <div id="playZone">Playzone: {{vm.currentCard}}</div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card" ng-repeat="card in ['one','two','three']" ng-click="vm.cardMove(card)"> {{card}} </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```